# Visual Studio 2015 Typescript Cannot Recognize Imported Members and Modules

Tags: angular, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 to create an Angular 2 app with Typescript. I am having an error when I import rxjs operator map on my service.

[image: Visual Studio Module Resolution Problem]

I already import the said operator but it seems Visual Studio 2015 still cannot find it as seen in the above image. I can F12 on the import statement it brings me to the correct file. Here is my tsconfig.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "typings"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Note that I specifically said that this problem in only in **Visual Studio 2015**. I tried this in **Visual Studio Code** and it can resolve it properly.

Is Visual Studio 2015's support for typescript not that polished yet like Visual Studio Code's? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is Visual Studio 2015's support for typescript not that polished yet like Visual Studio Code's

Yes. You need to setup the latest compiler which is a bit involved.

Docs : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Dev-Mode-in-Visual-Studio

Comment: I looked at the linked article but TypeScriptLanguageService is missing in the VisualStudio/14.0 path. I already installed the latest typescript installer for VS2015 in it's website.